# Objective C- How to get index of an object in the Array

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Let's say `Items` is a `NSMutableArray`. I want to know the index of the item object in its `Items` array. I can accomplish this by putting a counter "i" but that's ugly. Is there an elegant way of doing this?

```
for(item* item in Items){

  //do something with the item considering its **index** in the Items array

}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[indexOfObject:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/indexOfObject%3a)
[indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/indexOfObjectIdenticalTo%3a)

Edit:
Read carefully the descriptions, indexOfObjectIdenticalTo: is probably what you want in your case. 
However, adding a counter is the fast way in this case.

Answer (score 15):

What's wrong with the `indexOfObject:` method?

```
NSUInteger i = [ array indexOfObject: anObject ];
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want a counter in your for loop, instead use `NSMutableArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock`. This will iterate the elements and give you the index as an argument in the block you provide. Doing this will be a lot more performant that `indexOfObject` - which has to search the entire array before returning an index. It seems silly to use when you already 'know' the index.